# SQL error SQLState 08001 from MS Access 2010 runtime 32bit

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access-2010

My Problem is that I cannot connect to an SQL Server Express 2008 64bit Database via an Access Runtime 32bit, neither by Windows authentification nor by SQL auth.

On the Windows 2011 Small Business Server runs a Virtual machine with Windows 7 Prof. 32 bit. From this Windows I tested my Access App. using a (32bit) SQL Driver 11, which works fine.

The same Access App used from a 64 bit Windows 7 Prof. Client using a 64bit SQL Driver 11 fails with SQLState 08001 error.

The Thing which I do not understand is, that ODBC Connection test is successful, a data link (UDL) is successful, but not my Access App. 
When starting the app, the first Thing is to run a stored procedure through a passthrougquery and grab data from a certain tbl in the SQL-Database. This SP brings the Connection error, but not an runtime error from Access (I removed even an error handler!).

So, how can I find the reason or any error in the Access app (if there is one)?

I am helpless as anything I know to test or to do I already tried out to make the app run. As I cannot even install the SQL Driver 11 in 32bit, it should not be a Driver related error.

Does anyone know a test-app, where I cannot only connect but retrieve data from an SQL-Database or any other tricks to check the Access to the database?
Thanks your help!

Answer (score 0):

Access usually is installed as a 32bit Application. So on 64bit computers it will use the 32bit subsystem. On Windows 7 all the default shortcuts to the ODBC Data Source Administrator utility will lead to the 64bit version of it. Whatever you see or configure there is completely irrelevant, as your 32bit Access is not going to see it.

**Solution:**
You need to explicitely open the 32bit version of the ODBC Admin utility and configure the data source there. 
To make sure you get the right version, use Windows Explorer and open this file: `C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\odbcad32.exe`

Comment: Well, what I found out meanwhile is, that the Connection Fails when trying to use a Connection like this "ODBC; DSN=MyDSN;....." but it works, when I make a Connection DNS-less, by connecting with "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 11; SErver=myServer;....".

Answer (score 0):

Well, what I found out meanwhile is, that the Connection Fails when trying to use a Connection like this "ODBC; DSN=MyDSN;....." but it works, when I make a Connection DNS-less, by connecting with "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 11; SErver=myServer;....".

Maybe this is exactly that what you are talking aout. When I just use a DSN it takes the wrong bit Version.

So I will try this: delete the DSN I have, open odbcad32.exe and  create the same DSN again.

If I understand you correct, then Win 7 provides the correct Driver and stores it in the DSN. Calling this DSN by Access would lead to the correct Settings.

Further Problem is, that my SSQL-Server instance is not at port 1434, and the SQL Server Native Client 11 Driver has no more Clientconfiguartion to set the static port. So I found a string solution for that "MyServer\Myinstance, 15999".

I hope that this port Setting will be accepted in the DSN, otherwise I really have to Change to DSN-less which is more complicated due to different Servers for the development and the production.
Thanks yr. reply.